# Client socket on android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to send a single string from android to pc and after a bit of research on this site and others I've found out about sockets and how to use them. I have written the server program that can receive strings sent to it. Below is the code.

```
//static ServerSocket variable
    private static ServerSocket server;
    //socket server port on which it will listen
    private static int port = 9021;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

        server = new ServerSocket(port);


        while(true){
            System.out.println("Waiting for client request." + InetAddress.getLocalHost());

            Socket socket = server.accept();

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            String message = (String)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message received: " + message);

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            oos.writeObject("Hi Client: " + message);

            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();


            if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down serve");

        server.close();
    }
```

I have tested this using a pc client program that sends string and have confirmed that this server script works. I am trying to now implement the same concept in android but facing a lot of trouble mostly due to the fact that the tutorials online for this task is very outdated (2-3 years) so nothing works as expected. Can anyone tell me how to write a very simple android app in which a single string is sent over socket?

From what I can see in the logcat, the outdated tutorials on the internet are not working because android has apparently introduced in recent versions a very aggressive process manager which monitors the behaviour of threads and if there is any repeated thread actions, it shuts it down without notice.

Edit: As per a solution I have implemented an asynctask. But now the server is not receiving and says Address already in use. I think it is because of socket address in my android code. Please help!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Button button;
     private EditText message;
     private TextView finalResult;


     //InetAddress host;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_time);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_do_it);
        finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        /*
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                String msg = message.getText().toString();
                runner.execute(msg);

            }
        });

    }



    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        int clientport = 8080;
        String resp;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress("Sending...");

            String msg = params[0];


            for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){

                //establish socket connection to server
                try {
                    socket = new Socket( "100.69.73.16",clientport);
                    //write to socket using Objectouputstream
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(msg+i);


                    oos.close();
                    socket.close();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }



            resp = "Message has been sent";
            return resp;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            finalResult.setText(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

             finalResult.setText(values[0]);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Firstly you have to use an Asynctask in which you make the connection to the server.

Comment: How you connected with your PC? Over WiFi ? Or on network ??

Comment: Thank you for the asynctask suggestion. I have written an app using that and it succeeds in sending a msg. But now my server is not receiving it. It brings up an error and says - Address already in use: JVM_bind. I will add my android app code to the original post so that you can take a look.

Aiyaz, it is over wifi. Thank you for the interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved the problem of 'address already used' by changing port number. Apparently the port number was being used by other programs on my laptop. So in retrospect for anyone checking on how to do this, you can use my above code and remember to change the port number in both codes to something similar. Also in my android code where the socket is opened, you can put in the local ip address (very important, google gives you external) for your computer.